# Recuento observaciones distintas de 0

Tags: r

Quiero saber cuantas observaciones hay con valor diferente de 0.
Ej variable "valor": 1 5 6 0 8 0 1 0 0 -> 5

He probado:

```
df$Nueva.variable<-sum(df$valor !=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo es correcto:

```
v <- c(1,5,6,0,8,0,1,0,0)
sum(v != 0)
5
```

Pero, es la forma para saber la cantidad de valores no 0 en un vector, pero cuando hablas de observaciones, entiendo que hablas de "filas" de un `data.frame` o matriz, si es esto lo que buscas, podrías partiendo de algo así:

```
set.seed(2021)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:5,0), 20, replace = TRUE), ncol=5))
df

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  0  4  0  4  3
2  0  0  0  3  4
3  2  0  5  4  5
4  4  3  1  2  3
```

Hacer algo como esto:

```
df$distinto_de_0 <- rowSums(df != 0, na.rm=TRUE)
df

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 distinto_de_0
1  0  4  0  4  3             3
2  0  0  0  3  4             2
3  2  0  5  4  5             4
4  4  3  1  2  3             5
```

Comment: No funciona. Si antes de "!=" pongo solo df me sale todo NA y si pongo df$variable me dice " 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions"

Comment: Seguramente tienes valores `NA` en todas las filas, prueba ignorándolos, con `rowSums(df!=0, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

Soy muy novato en R pero quizás podrías factorizar y extraer lo que quieres.

Factorizar es crear valores únicos del vector.

Combinado con 'summary' te da totales por valor, las frecuencias absolutas. En otras palabras, te dice cuántas veces aparece cada valor único.

Y con tail, extraemos por el final, omitiendo el cero.

```
test<-c(1,5,6,0,8,0,1,0,0) # Metemos Valores

factores_test<-factor(test) # Sacamos factores

# Los factores, por defecto, salen ordenados de a-Z y -+ así que el 0 estará el primero


resultado<-tail(summary(factores_test), length(summary(factores_test))-1) #guardamos todos los factores menos el primero, el cero

resultado
```

Este código devuelve cuántas veces aparece cada valor diferente a 0.

```
1 5 6 8 
2 1 1 1
```

Si lo único que quieres saber es cuántos valores diferentes a 0 hay, puedes simplificarlo y simplemente

```
test<-c(1,5,6,0,8,0,1,0,0) # Metemos Valores

factores_test<-factor(test) # Sacamos factores

length(levels(factores_test)[levels(factores_test)!=0])
```

Con esto obtendrás cuántos valores diferentes a 0 hay en tu vector, independientemente de cuántas veces aparezca cada uno. Me devuelve:

```
[1] 4
```